# Error with writeobject and String in java

Tags: java

I have a client and server which I exchange messages and objects between.
My problem is when I send object with the help of `toString` and a string together. How do I pick out the object from the string and add the object to a list ;
I wrote the code.

**Server code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Server  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <PhoneBook> listPhone=new ArrayList<PhoneBook>(); 

    PhoneBook a = new PhoneBook("a","a","","",1);
    listPhone.add(a);
    PhoneBook pB = new PhoneBook();
    String ob;
    try{

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5555,50);

        System.out.println("Waiting Incoming Connection...");
        System.out.println("Local Address :"+server.getInetAddress()+" Port :"+server.getLocalPort());
        Socket sock = server.accept();

        ObjectOutputStream out =new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()); 
        ObjectInputStream  in =new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream()); 

        String strin =(String) in.readObject();

        if (strin.equals("START")){ 
        out.writeObject("WAITING");
        out.flush();}
        strin =(String) in.readObject();
        String[] str=strin.split("\n");
        if(str[0].equals("REQUEST_SEARCH")){

               try{
                    // in this line is error
                   pB = (PhoneBook)in.readObject();  //String cannot be cast to PhoneBook
                   out.flush();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
          System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");}
               out.writeObject("RECORSDS"); 
               out.flush(); 
               String sName = pB.getsurName(); 
               for(int i=0;i<listPhone.size();i++) 
              if(listPhone.get(i).getsurName().equals(sName)){ 
              out.writeObject(pB.toString()); 
              out.flush(); 

        }else{
        out.writeObject("NXRECORD");
        out.flush();
        }}
        strin =(String) in.readObject();
        String[] st=strin.split("\n");

        if(st[0].equals("REQUEST_INSERT")){

            listPhone.add(pB); 
            System.out.println("The contact is add");
            out.writeObject("OK");
            out.flush();
        }
        out.flush();

        if(strin.equals("END")){ //bye = terminate the conversation

        in.close();
        out.close();
        sock.close();
        System.out.println("Connection Closing...");}
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error during I/O");
        ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        } } }
```

**Client code:**

```
     if (strin.equals("WAITING")) {
        System.out.println("The server says: " + strin);
        // out.writeObject("REQUEST_SEARCH\n");
        // out.flush();
        System.out.println("The server says: " + strin);
        System.out.print("Write the contact elements ");
        System.out.print("Write the name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Write the surname: ");
        String surName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Write the job: ");
        String job = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Write the street: ");
        String street = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Write the phone number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        PhoneBook p = new PhoneBook(name, surName, job, street, number);
        out.writeObject("REQUEST_SEARCH\n" + p.toString());
        out.flush();
    }
```

**The error:**

```
Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)     at
java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)  at
java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source) at 
       java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)    at
       java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)     at Server.main
```

**Application background:**

This program is a PhooneBook with contacts (the server) and the client send first a START and the server take it and send WAITING after the client make a object phonebook which include *name, surname, job, street and phone* and sends it with the message REQUEST_SEARCH the server take the message and object (the contact) and search in array list with *lastname* if exist a contact, if exist send back the object and show the *name, surname, job* and other with `toString()` and message RECORDS then client send OK and server send back END and connection is closing if the contact is not exist the server send the message NXRECORD the client sent back a message REQUEST_INSERT the server take it and add the object in arraylist and sent OK And client send back END and closing connection.

Comment: If you're using eclipse, format your code using `CTRL+SHIFT+F`..

Comment: This Exception is comming at client side?

Comment: From server is comming

Comment: Can you tell at which line? and if possible put the complete code..

Comment: under of this commend is the error of eclipse // in this line is error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are sending to server after this line.

```
out.writeObject("REQUEST_SEARCH\n" + p.toString());
```

But I assume that you are sending a `String`  to Server .
Whereas at Server side while retrieving it you are typeCasting  it to `PhoneBook` instead of `String`  using following line:

```
pB = (PhoneBook)in.readObject();
```

That's leading to stream mismatch..Hence the exception is arising.
The solution to this problem could be as follows: I assume that your `PhoneBook` class is `Serializable`.

At client side use :

```
 out.writeObject("REQUEST_SEARCH\n" + p.toString());
 out.writeObject(p);//Given that PhoneBook is Serializable.
```

Comment: after the change the program take the element of contact and closing the connection is not make a search for contact the server